# Расширить массив в публичном свойстве

Tags: c#, массивы

В *Program.cs*:

```
static class p_data
{
    public static string[] dock_text  { get; set; }
}
```

в другом месте программы пытаюсь расширить:

```
 Array.Resize(ref p_data.dock_text, p_data.dock_text.Length + 1);
```

Выдаёт ошибку:

> A property, indexer or dynamic member access may not be passed as an out or ref parameter

Пожалуй, объясню поставленную задачу: динамически создаётся элемент, для примера `PictureBox`, при клике по последнему открывается форма с `TextBox`, в который вводятся данные, и эти данные нужно как-то хранить, вот для этого и использую массив.

Comment: а почему бы вместо шаманств с Resize не воспользоваться классом, который как раз представляет собой динамический массив? То есть List<T>

Comment: @DreamChild а к `List<T>` можно обращаться по индексу? `List<T>[1]` если нет, то не подходит )

Comment: можно конечно же. Это динамический массив, неужели не знаете?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам в ошибке явно сказали: нужно поле, а не свойство. Уберите `{ get; set; }` у `dock_text`, поле из автоматического свойства "извлечь" не получится. При желании можно обернуть в неавтоматическое свойство.

А вообще, у меня ощущение, что вы пришли из другого языка на C#, судя по стилю именования, который не имеет с традициями C# ничего общего. Советую ознакомиться с тем, как дела делаются здесь. В частности, обычно используют классы коллекций вроде `List<>`.

И даже в том случае, если вам действительно нужен `Array.Resize`, изменять размер на один элемент — это плохая идея, потому что вы убьёте производительность, если будете делать это ради каждого элемента.

`Array.Resize` никакой магии не совершает, он *создаёт новый массив* и копирует в него содержимое старого. Старый массив при этом остаётся для обработки сборщиком мусора.

Comment: из парочки других ) Delphi и php. За `List<>` Знаю, но как к его элементам тогда обращаться ? Это же не именованный список выходит. Изменю по 1 т.к. задача стоит именно такая, а создавать десяток лишних элементов не хочется. @Discord

Comment: @VladimirH Что значит "как обращаться"? Как и у массива, по индексу. Переходите на `List<string>`, у вас некорректные представления о работе с памятью после PHP (элементы не создадутся, списки традиционно наращивают экспоненциально, обычно по степеням двойки). Дельфовый `StringList` и похапэшный `array` прячут эту магию от вас, как и `List<string>` в шарпе. Пользуйтесь.

Comment: @Discort 4 месяца как C# мучаю ) Не успел ещё со всеми тонкостями ознакомится, а в плане именования немного не понял, Camel style?

Comment: @VladimirH PascalCase для всего публичного, camelCase для параметров, приватные члены не оговариваются (обычно пользуются camelCase или _camelCase для полей экземпляра, например). https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms229043.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Нужно сначала сохранить его в переменную, а потом расширить.

```
var x = p_data.dock_text;
Array.Resize(ref x, x.Length + 1);
p_data.dock_text = x;
```

UPD

Ну и лучше было бы использовать [List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).